# Stepper Motor not rotating properly/precisely

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, stepper

I would like to control a tray to move back and forth automatically between several positions automatically.

**Hardware**: arduino nano / mega, [TMC2209](https://www.trinamic.com/products/integrated-circuits/details/tmc2209-la/) and [TB6600](https://www.mcielectronics.cl/website_MCI/static/documents/TB6600_data_sheet.pdf) stepper motor drivers, stepper motor [23HS84830](https://www.amazon.de/-/en/Nema23-Stepper-23HS8430-270oz-Diameter/dp/B01CYIU0EG/ref=sr_1_4?dchild=1&keywords=schrittmotor+act+motor+23hs8430&qid=1602670551&sr=8-4).

**Power Supply**: 12V/5A

**Problem:** I wrote the code and noticed that although the interval between positions was fixed, the tray would move a little bit more each time therefore missing the position. At the last position it would be really off position.

**Attempted Solutions**: To solve this I decided to write a serial command sketch that would allow me to simulate this behaviour, define intervals, number of positions, cycles, laps, microstepping, see code below.

[image]

I had just run a sequence and made it back to the main menu. these are all the options that can be configured.

Made some trials and noticed that my sketch was outputing exactly what I configured in the right way (see picture of logic analyzer below).
[image: image description here]

In this picture the what happens is:

1. stepper motor rotates 5 laps (8000 steps) and waits 0,5 seconds before rotating again. repeats 5 times.
2. changes direction
3. does the same as step 1

What I did to try and solve the problem so far:

- changed between TMC2209 and TB6600 to see if the problem would be the driver: it wasn't happens with both drivers
- checked with the logic analyzer if the problem was the code: it wasn't, output of code is consistent and easily measurable
- reviewed the connections of the stepper motor coils. not a problem and according to the motor datasheet/stepper motor driver datasheet.

At this moment, I cannot understand why the motor is not moving correctly and I would appreciate experienced support to solve this since it seems quite trivial but I cannot find the bug.

Thanks!

```
int PUL=4; //define Pulse pin
int DIR=3; //define Direction pin
int ENA=2; //define Enable Pin

#define left 1
#define right 0
#define LEFT 1
#define RIGHT 0

int steps_per_revolution = 200;
int minutes = 60;
long int input_value = 0;
long int _speed = 0;
long int temp_speed_rpm = 0;
long int speed_rpm = 0;
long int steps = 0;
int cycles = 0;
int positions = 0;
long int laps = 0;
long int rpm = 0;
int microstepping = 0;
long int total_laps = 0;

// Serial Commands
String command;
String inString = "";

// control flag to show the menu
boolean refresh_commands = false;

// DIRECTION LOW - MOVES RIGHT
// DIRECTION HIGH - MOVES LEFT

void setup() {
  pinMode (PUL, OUTPUT);
  pinMode (DIR, OUTPUT);
  pinMode (ENA, OUTPUT);

  Serial.begin(115200);

  menu_print();
}
void loop()
{
  if(Serial.available()){
        command = Serial.readStringUntil('\n');
        if(command.equals("p")){

            variable_print();
            
            refresh_commands = true;
        }
        if(command.equals("ss")){
            Serial.println("0");
            _speed = input_data();
            Serial.print(_speed);
            Serial.println(" uS");
            refresh_commands = true;
        }
        if(command.equals("ssr")){
            Serial.println("ssr");
            temp_speed_rpm = input_data();
            _speed = calculate_speed(temp_speed_rpm);
                        
            refresh_commands = true;
        }
        if(command.equals("sd")){                   // checks if one direction is set, changes and then changes back again
            if(digitalRead(DIR) == HIGH)
            {
              change_direction(right);
              Serial.println("Direction changed to: RIGHT");
            }
            else
            {
              if(digitalRead(DIR) == LOW)
              {
                change_direction(left);
                Serial.println("Direction changed to: LEFT");
              }
            }
        
            refresh_commands = true;
        }
        if(command.equals("sst")){
            Serial.println("sst");
            steps = input_data();
            Serial.println(" ");
            Serial.print(steps);
            Serial.println(" - steps configured");
            refresh_commands = true;
        }
        if(command.equals("sm")){
            Serial.println("sm");
            Serial.println("sm --> how many microsteps?");
            microstepping = input_data();
            Serial.println(microstepping);
            refresh_commands = true;
        }
        if(command.equals("sp")){
            Serial.println("sp");
            positions = input_data();
            Serial.println("sp --> Configure Positions");
            Serial.println(positions);
            refresh_commands = true;
        }
        if(command.equals("sc")){
            Serial.println("sc");
            cycles = input_data();
            Serial.println("sc --> Configure Cycles");
            Serial.println(cycles);
            refresh_commands = true;
        }
        if(command.equals("sl")){
            Serial.println("sl");
            Serial.println("sl --> how many laps?");
            laps = input_data();
            Serial.print(laps);
            refresh_commands = true;
        }
        if(command.equals("1")){
            Serial.println("1");
            change_direction(left);
            steps = input_data();       // Asks before for how many steps to rotate and changes the value.
            rotate_motor(steps);
            refresh_commands = true;
        }
        if(command.equals("2")){
            Serial.println("2");
            change_direction(right);
            steps = input_data();       // Asks before for how many steps to rotate and changes the value.
            rotate_motor(steps);
            refresh_commands = true;
        }
        if(command.equals("3")){
            Serial.println("3");
            change_direction(left);
            rotate_motor(steps);
            refresh_commands = true;
        }
        if(command.equals("4")){
            Serial.println("4");
            change_direction(right);
            rotate_motor(steps);
            refresh_commands = true;
        }
        if(command.equals("rs")){
            Serial.println("rs --> Run Sequence");
            variable_print();
            delay(3000);
            total_laps = laps * steps_per_revolution * microstepping;
            // run the planned sequence
            run_sequence(cycles, positions);
            refresh_commands = true;
        }
        if(command.equals("rl")){
            Serial.println("rl");
            Serial.println("rl --> how any laps? ");
            variable_print();
            delay(3000);
            total_laps = laps * steps_per_revolution * microstepping;
            // calculate laps and activate motor
            run_laps();
            refresh_commands = true;
        }
        else{
           Serial.println("Invalid command");
           refresh_commands = true;
        }        
        refresh_commands = true;            // added here to remove from all other commands
    }
    if (refresh_commands == true){
      menu_print();
      refresh_commands = false;
    }
}

void run_sequence(int cycles, int positions){
  int j = 0;
  
  
  for(j=0; j<cycles; j++)
  {
    Serial.print("Cycle:      ");
    Serial.println(j);
    // Start always moving to LEFT
    change_direction(left);
    Serial.println("Direction changed to: LEFT");
    
    for(int i=0; i<positions; i++)
    {
      Serial.print("FWD Pos.: ");
      Serial.println(i);
      rotate_motor(total_laps);
      delay(500);
    }
    delay(1000);
    //change_direction(right);
    change_direction(right);
    Serial.println("Direction changed to: RIGHT");
    delay(100);
    
    for(int i=0; i<positions; i++)
    {
      Serial.print("BWD Pos.: ");
      Serial.println(i);
      rotate_motor(total_laps);
      delay(500);
    }
  }
}

void run_laps(){
//  long int total_laps = 0;
//  total_laps = laps * steps_per_revolution * microstepping;
//  moved to the main cycle and changed run_sequence to include the laps
  Serial.print("Total Laps Steps: ");         // to be tested.
  Serial.println(total_laps);

  Serial.print("Laps: ");         // to be tested.
  Serial.println(laps);

  Serial.print("Steps/rev: ");         // to be tested.
  Serial.println(steps_per_revolution);

  Serial.print("MicroStepping: ");         // to be tested.
  Serial.println(microstepping);

  // change direction
  change_direction(left);

  // rotate motor
  rotate_motor(total_laps);              // variables must be long otherwise we cannot do the same number of steps as others

  delay(1000);

  // change direction
  change_direction(right);

  // rotate motor
  rotate_motor(total_laps);

  Serial.print(laps);
  Serial.println(" - Laps completed.");
}

int input_data(){
  int inChar = 0;
  boolean flag = false;
  
  Serial.println("How many?");
  Serial.println(" ");

  do{
     while (Serial.available() > 0) {
        inChar = Serial.read();
        if (isDigit(inChar)) {
          // convert the incoming byte to a char and add it to the string:
          inString += (char)inChar;
        }
        // if you get a newline, print the string, then the string's value:
        if (inChar == '\n') {
          input_value = inString.toInt();
          
          // clear the string for new input:
          inString = "";
          flag = true;
        }
//        // if the received char is an 'Z', then it triggers a flag to leave the menu
//        if(inChar == 'Z')
//        {
//          flag = true;
//        }
      }
  }while(!flag);
  
  return input_value;
}

void rotate_motor(long int motor_steps){
  Serial.print("Starting Rotation -->  ");
  Serial.println(motor_steps);

  long int i=0;
  
  digitalWrite(ENA, LOW);
  for (i=0; i<motor_steps; i++)
  {
    digitalWrite(PUL,HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(_speed);
    digitalWrite(PUL,LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(_speed);
  }
  Serial.print("i -->  ");
  Serial.print(i);
  digitalWrite(ENA, HIGH);
  Serial.println("Finished rotation!");
}

void change_direction(bool direction){
  delayMicroseconds(500);
    digitalWrite(ENA,HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(100);
    digitalWrite(DIR,direction);
  delayMicroseconds(500);
    digitalWrite(ENA,LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(100);
    Serial.print("Read Dir: ");
    Serial.println(digitalRead(DIR));
}

void menu_print(){
  Serial.println(" ");
  Serial.println("p --> Display Parameters");
  Serial.println("ss --> Set Speed (tON/tOFF)");
  Serial.println("ssr --> Set Speed (RPM)");
  Serial.println("sd --> Configure direction");
  Serial.println("sst --> Set Steps");
  Serial.println("sm --> Set MicroStepping (default = 1)");
  Serial.println("sp --> Set Positions");
  Serial.println("sc --> Set Cycles");
  Serial.println("sl --> Set Laps");
  Serial.println("1 --> Move LEFT x steps");
  Serial.println("2 --> Move RIGHT x steps");
  Serial.println("3 --> Move LEFT 1 position");
  Serial.println("4 --> Move RIGHT 1 position");
  Serial.println("rs --> Run Sequence");
  Serial.println("rl --> Run Laps");
  Serial.println(" ");
}

void variable_print(){
  Serial.print("Speed:         ");
  Serial.print(_speed); 
  Serial.println(" us");
  Serial.print("Speed:         ");
  Serial.print(temp_speed_rpm); 
  Serial.println(" RPM");
  Serial.print("Steps:         ");
  Serial.println(steps);
  Serial.print("Microstepping: ");
  Serial.println(microstepping);
  Serial.print("Positions:     ");
  Serial.println(positions);
  Serial.print("Cycles:        ");
  Serial.println(cycles);
  Serial.print("Laps:          ");
  Serial.println(laps);
  Serial.print("Direction:     ");
  read_direction();                    
}

bool read_direction(){
  //bool dir_state = 0;
  
  if(digitalRead(DIR) == HIGH)
  {
    Serial.println("LEFT");
  }
  else
  {
    if(digitalRead(DIR) == LOW)
    {
      Serial.println("RIGHT");
    }
  }
  return digitalRead(DIR);
}

long int calculate_speed(long int _speed){
  
  float steps_per_second = 0;         // truncating a float to int -> error chance here
  float temp_speed = 0;
  

  Serial.print("FUNCTION: Calculate_speed: ");
  Serial.print(_speed);
  Serial.println(" RPM");

  steps_per_second = (_speed * steps_per_revolution) / minutes;
  
  Serial.print("FUNCTION: steps_per_second: ");
  Serial.println(steps_per_second);

  temp_speed = (1 / steps_per_second);

  temp_speed = temp_speed / 2;        // to find Ton and Toff
  temp_speed = temp_speed / 0.000001; // to convert to microseconds (input to delayMicroseconds() function)

  temp_speed = (int) temp_speed;

//  Serial.print("FUNCTION: _speed in microseconds:  ");
//  Serial.print(temp_speed,5);
//  Serial.println(" uS");

  Serial.print("FUNCTION: _speed in microseconds:  ");
  Serial.print(temp_speed);
  Serial.println(" uS");
    
  return temp_speed;
}
```

Comment: if you're producing the right number of steps and your positioning is off you're most likely losing steps.

Comment: The motor has no load. It cannot miss steps. I have no reason to doubt this. But thanks for your feedback